# Why do I fail to connect to local ssh server passphrase-free?

Tags: ssh

I tried to make ssh connection to local ssh server passphrase-free:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
config  id_dsa  id_dsa.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  known_hosts.old


$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-VYbFIb5qW0vi/agent.28080; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=28085; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 28085;

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /home/t/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/t/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

But why do I still need to provide passphrase? Thanks.

```
$ ssh t@localhost
t@localhost's password: 

$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  t@localhost
t@localhost's password:
```

Answer (score 1):

The targeted host must have an `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file containing the public keys for those who are given access. So, in your case, you would do

```
$ cp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod go= $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The latter of those commands makes the file inaccessible for anyone but the `$USER`.

Comment: Thanks. What does "=" in "go=" do?

Comment: After following your commands, do I still need to run `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: the `go=` part says the group and other should have no permissions. E.g. you'd use `go=r` to give group and other read permission, or `go=rw` to giv group and other read and write permission. see `man chmod` for more.

Comment: If your key has a password, then yes; the agent is a client end facility to provide the key to successive ssh, letting you give the key password only once. If your key is password-less, then you don't need the agent.